# How to make OWIN self-host MVC write directly to output stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm using an MVC action under OWIN self-host application which serves a bulk of bytes to the client as a file. The data is generated in-memory and cached and the MVC action returns a `StreamContent` with a `MemoryStream` pointing to my cached `byte[]`.

I expected that the data would be read directly from my cache and copied to the `OutputStream`. Instead the data is copied from my `MemoryStream` to a different one created by the infrastructure. When making a lot of requests in parallel I can see the process memory grows:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(content), content.Length)
    {
        Headers =
        {
            ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileNameStar = fileName,
                Size = content.Length,
            },
            ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(mediaType),
            ContentLength = content.Length,
        }
    }
};
```

How can I make sure I return my cached `MemoryStream` directly without it being copied which occupies more memory?

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this you can write directly to the `OutputStream` by getting it from the OWIN environment with `Request.GetOwinEnvironment()`. To get the response content written you can use `PushStreamContent` and write to the `OutputStream` with the async callback called when the response is being constructed.

```
    var outputStream = ((HttpListenerContext)Request.GetOwinEnvironment()["System.Net.HttpListenerContext"]).Response.OutputStream;
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new PushStreamContent(
            async (stream, httpContent, arg3) =>
            {
                await outputStream.WriteAsync(content, 0, content.Length);
                stream.Close();
            })
        {
            Headers =
            {
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileNameStar = fileName,
                    Size = content.Length,
                },
                ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(mediaType),
                ContentLength = content.Length,
            }
        }
    };
```